# address and phone number displaying with blue line in gmail

Tags: php, css, hyperlink, gmail

I have no anchor tag in my code. Below is my code:

```
<span id='linkRemove'> address </span>
```

when I try to send email as HTML the Gmail is automatically generating a blue link (hyperlink to google map). I have used below solution (css):

```
.linkRemove {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

`color:inherit` and `text-decoration:none` is working !!

`pointer-events: none;` and `cursor: default;` is not working

I want to stop the gmail creating it, or I want this (`pointer-events: none;`) to work on gmail

Comment: `cursor: default` if you want a default so no need to write it will come by default only. Make snippet of your code.

Comment: for cursor: default  is oky, what about pointer-events: none; frd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a style="text-decoration: none !important; color: #ffffff !important;">address</a>
```

Please put your suitable color code as per your need.
In my case it soved. Hope, this may solve yours too.

Comment: it automatically generating.

Comment: Yes it generates automatically with gmail. In my case, I wrap the address with <a> tag and put these css solved my issue.

Comment: its only changing the color of the link

Comment: Can you share me the whole line that you currently use on email? So I can try with mine.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Google does some kind of "post processing" with emails. They want to help the user get things done quickly, so they automatically detect stuff like addresses, phone numbers or emails and create anchor tags with links for them. So the user only has to click on them instead of copying and pasting the text manually.

The reason why two of our CSS properties work, and the others don't is, because the `pointer-events` and `cursor` property is not supported by Gmail ([Source](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/cursor/)). I think Apple Mail does the same thing, I had to deal with it a few years ago and did not find any solution, unfortunaly.

So, what you **can** do is styling the link to make it look like regular text, but what you **can't** do is to prevent the click action, since the anchor tag gets added by the mail client itself.